# How can I construct the random effects model matrix from a mixed model formula

Tags: r, mixed-model, python, inference, random-effects-model

Let us say we have a mixed effects model formula. For example, in R using lme4, consider two formulas:

```
Y~X1+X2+(1|fac)
```

and

```
Y~X1+X2+(X1|fac)
```

where `X1` and `X2` are fixed effects, and `fac` is a random effect. Other software such as `lme` in R or `statsmodels` in Python could equally be used but it seems the `lme4` formula is more common.

Can we construct the random effects model matrix, $Z$, that we see in the general mixed model equation:

$$y = X\beta+Zu+e$$

for each of the formulas above **before** we have seen the data ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can we construct the random effects model matrix, Z, that we see in the general mixed model equation ... for each of the formulas above before we have seen the data ?

No.

This is impossible without the data

For the same reason that we cannot construct the fixed effects model matrix $X$ we cannnot construct the random effects model matrix either, because they both depend on the data.

This is why the general mixed effects model formula is called "general".